# sporadic timeouts on http connection

Tags: android, http

In my application I use http to connect to my server (I am synchronizing the local database). Here is the code:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
httpClient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpClient.getParams(),13500);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpClient.getParams(),27000);

HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpRequest); 
int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
if (entity != null) {
    String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(data);
    entity.consumeContent();
}
```

This code is executed for a number of httpRequests to pull the data from the server as well as to send updates up to the server.

Till recently this code did not give me any trouble, but now I am struggling with a strange problem: Sometime the code works as it is supposed to work, but sometimes all I am getting is timeouts.

A little more details - when it does not work it is not like I am getting sporadic timeouts - every request I send ends up with a timeout. I can restart the app and see this behavior, and then after several app restarts it is like the curse is lifted - not a single timeout. And then again all I am getting is timeouts.

I am pretty sure that the problem is on the phone side, because I also have an IPhone app talking to the same app with no problems. Also several times I observed this problem with one android device, while the same app on a different device working fine.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem?

Comment: Nope. The problem just went away. I am sure it is waiting for the best moment to show up again :)